# Esta bien el uso de "do while " en c# para esta ocasión

Tags: c#

EL metodo si me funciona pero al consumir el servicio en la cual a veces puede que se caiga o algo similar impidiendo la consulta por eso hize un do while hasta que sea diferente de "-1" ya que es el codigo(estado) de cuando no reconoce la consulta. Estaria bien el uso o como sugieren que pueda hacerlo

```
string estado = String.Empty;
string detalle = String.Empty;
string cdr = String.Empty;

do
{
    var k = entidad.ConsultarEstado(c11, co, x, y, out  estado, out  cdr, out  detalle);

} while (estado == "-1");
```

Comment: El uso del `do...while` me parece correcto aquí, pero me parece un poco raro que la función `ConsultarEstado()` te devuelva una cadena con el valor `"-1"` ¿no será un entero? Es decir, que la condición sería `while(estado==-1)`. Por otro lado, si el servicio está caido, el repetir la consulta inmediatamente puede llevar a un elevadísimo número de reintentos, que en realidad podrían agravar el problema (sobrecarga del servidor). Es habitual hacer una espera entre reintentos (e incluso que el valor de la espera vaya creciendo).

Comment: ConsultarEstado() son todos string entonces para no sobrecargar el servidor podria usar 'Threading.Thread.Sleep' en caso de que bote ese estado gracias por responder

Comment: ¿Para qué utilizarías Threading.Thread.Sleep? hasta donde se, eso bloquearía el proceso principal.